# Making the "git branch area" from Android Studio larger

Tags: android, android-studio

Does anyone know a way to enlarge the area where one can see the current branch? There are lots of free space at the left and it would be helpful to know at first sight in which branch you are working

[image: Git branch area]

**Update:**

I dont know in which version it got improved, but using *Android Studio 3.1.2* the mentioned area resizes itself so the whole branch name is displayed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no solution for this problem. An [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-73669#u=1402136486591&tab=Similar%20Issues) was opened with jetbrains for this problem on **29 Aug 2011**. Even though the issue priority was reported as **Major**, the issue is still open and there are no fixes for this scenario.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am going to wait a couple of days to see if someone has come up with a personal solution or knows a way in AndroidStudio, and if not, I will mark your solution as the correct one, ok?

Comment: @AlvaroSantisteban sure Alvaro.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly getting but whatever I understand, you can enlarge it bu alt+9 or go to View --> Tool Windows --> Version Control,

It will show you details of files which are required to upload on branch and all.